# How can I get lxml.Element.xpath to not expand entities?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

If I use `lxml.etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)` to parse XML content, it correctly returns text nodes without the entities expanded. (I'd prefer that it just leave the text of the entity in there; instead it truncates at the first entity.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from lxml import etree

xml_content = b"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [
  <!ELEMENT foo ANY>
  <!ENTITY bar "benign">
]>
<body>
    <expansion>    This is    a &bar; entity expansion with weird spacing.   </expansion>
</body>"""

nonexpanding_parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
unexpanded_tree = etree.parse(BytesIO(xml_content), nonexpanding_parser)
elements = unexpanded_tree.xpath('//expansion')
elements[0].text  # '    This is    a '
```

However, when I try to call the [xpath function normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) on it, it expands the entity, which I'm trying to avoid:

```
elements[0].xpath('normalize-space(.)')  # 'This is a benign entity expansion with weird spacing.'
```

I suppose I can write my own normalization method, but I'd rather avoid that and I'm not 100% sure what the exact spec of that function is, and I'm working on replacing it in my code, so I want it to behave the same.

**Really the question is**: Can I get something like `elements[0].xpath('normalize-space(.)')` that will return `This is a`.

Even better:

- `This is a entity expansion with weird spacing.` (this is the preferred example)
- `This is a &bar; entity expansion with weird spacing.`

Comment: I don't want to say this is the "answer" to my question because the reason I went with it involves aspects of the code _around_ this minimal example. Regardless, this is what I went with and thought it should be shared:

`import re`

`text = ' '.join(elements[0].itertext())`

`text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text.strip())`

Note that this produces the example with the unexpanded entity in it, which was acceptable for me under my conditions and tradeoffs

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly elegant, but you could extract all the text nodes, join them in Python, and normalize the space.

```
(Pdb) text_fragments = unexpanded_tree.xpath('//expansion/text()')
(Pdb) text_fragments
['    This is    a ', ' entity expansion with weird spacing.   ']
(Pdb) ' '.join(''.join(text_fragments).split())
'This is a entity expansion with weird spacing.'
```